# Self assessment questionaire tool for on premise installation

Tags: self-hosted

I need a tool that allows to design questionnaires for self assessment.

I do not want to use an online service, I want to install something on a (linux) server and run it.

Best would be something free, but something like 10$/user would also be fine.

Answer (score 1):

[Lime survey](https://www.limesurvey.org/)? It's not specifically designed for self assessment, but I can't see any limit in it that pervents you to use it for that purpose.

It offers a free CE version that you can [download](https://community.limesurvey.org/downloads/) ad install on premises.